# Creating custom feed for Web Platform Installer 3.0

Tags: feed, web-platform-installer

Does anyone know to create custom feed (xml) for Web PI 3.0??

Comment: http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-products.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit old, but is does the trick.

http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-products.aspx